# How to Open all URLs as http://www. instead of http:// in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, cookies, model-view-controller

I want my asp.net mvc website to open as www.xyz.com instead of xyz.com. I want to redirect every user who uses xyz.com to www.xyz.com. The reason why I am doing this is to maintain the cookies. As currently 2 different cookies sets one works for www.xyz.com and the other works for xyz.com. Kindly help me how to fix it.

Comment: Why not just set the cookie domain to xyz.com and then it'll be usable on both cases?

Answer (score 0):

Within the web.config of your site, you can specify URL rewriting rules.

You would want to add something like this in the system.WebServer section of your web.config.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirectdomain.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.com" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Here's a more in depth Microsoft blog about implementing the rewrite:

https://blogs.iis.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www

That being said, you can modify the cookie to be read by both www and non-www, as long as the domain name is the same.

I hope this helps!